# How can i drag Qtreewidget item?

Tags: python, pyqt5, qtreewidget

This is an example of using QTreeWidget and The image below is the execution result.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y6McX.png)

Just like dragging the text of Qlineedit or QTextEdit, I want to drag the text of the QtableWidget item. However, the Qtablewidget item is not dragged, only selected like my image.
Can i drag text of Qtreewidget item?
What should I do?

This is the example code I used.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QTreeWidget, QTreeWidgetItem
data = {"Project A": ["file_a.py", "file_a.txt", "something.xls"],
        "Project B": ["file_b.csv", "photo.jpg"],
        "Project C": []}

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
tree = QTreeWidget()
tree.setColumnCount(2)
tree.setHeaderLabels(["Name", "Type"])
items = []
for key, values in data.items():
    item = QTreeWidgetItem([key])
    for value in values:
        ext = value.split(".")[-1].upper()
        child = QTreeWidgetItem([value, ext])
        item.addChild(child)
    items.append(item)

tree.insertTopLevelItems(0, items)

tree.show()
sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Comment: By default, higher level views like QTreeWidget don't provide drag&drop, but you can enable it by using [`tree.setDragDropMode(tree.DragDrop)`](//doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemview.html#dragDropMode-prop). The real questions are: 1. do you want to enable drag&drop for *all* elements? 2. should all elements accept drops? 3. what should happen when you drop an element into another? All these questions (and the combination of their answers) can have different results, so I strongly suggest you to do some further, patient and careful research, as drag&drop is *tricky*, especially for tree models.

Comment: I'm sorry to the lack sufficient explanation of my question. DragDropMode seems to move the item. My question is whether there is a way to drag only the text of Project from the QtreeWidget item called Project A in the image.

Comment: Drag it where? Your example code is no use at all because it makes no attempt to implement anything. Tree-widget items are quite specialised objects, so most other widgets can't handle them by default (assuming they have been configured to accept drops at all, that is). Please read Qt's [Drag and Drop Overview](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/dnd.html) to at least get some idea of what's involved.